# php variables, strings and arrays: associative array returns first letter of string

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I understand that, with a sting assigned to a variable, individual characters can be expressed by using the variable as an indexed array, but why does the code below, using an associative array, not just die with missing required? Why does 'isset' not throw FALSE on an array key that definitely doesn't exist?

```
unset($a); 

$a = 'TESTSTRING'; 

if(!isset($a['anystring'])){ 
    die('MISSING REQUIRED'); 
}else{ 
    var_dump($a['anystring']);
}
```

The above example will output:

```
string(1) "T"
```

**EDIT:**

As indicated by Jelle Keiser, this is probably the safer thing to do:

```
if(!array_key_exists('required',$_POST)){ 
    die('MISSING REQUIRED'); 
}else{ 
    echo $_POST['required']; 
}
```

Comment: Interestingly only in 4.3.0 - 4.4.9 and 5.0.3 - 5.3.29 http://3v4l.org/vkgBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What PHP is doing is using your string as a numeric index. In this case, `'anystring'` is the equivalent of `0`. You can test this by doing

```
<?php
echo (int)'anystring';
// 0
var_dump('anystring' == 0);
// bool(true)
```

PHP does a lot of [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), which can lead to "interesting" results.

Answer (score 2):

$a is a string not an associative array.

If you want to access it that way you have to do something like this.

```
$a['anystring'] = 'TESTSTRING';
```

Comment: It's not that I'm trying to access it. I know how that would work. This is more of a abstract question I guess. I set $a as a string, and would expect, wrongly it turns out, that isset($a['anysting']) to be FALSE because I never set it. But it returns true. I just don't understand that mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  array_key_exists() to test if a key exists

Comment: this is a good point. I'll do this in the future. It looks like "isset" will not always give expected results when dealing with associative arrays. Thx

Answer (score 1):

The working of `isset` is  correct in your case.
Because `$a` is a string, the index-operator will give you the specified char in the string at the declared position. (like a "Char-Array")

A small example:

```
$a = 'TESTSTRING'; 
echo $a[0]; // Output: T
echo $a[1]; // Output: E
// ...
```

This will output the first and the second character at index 0 and 1 of the string.

And because the index-operator always expects an integer value on strings. The given value will be automatically casted to an integer. You can see this, when you cast the string to an integer, like this:

```
echo (int) 'TESTSTRING'; // Output: 0
```

For char-access on strings, also [see the PHP-Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr).

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling PHP to show all errors by using `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

This should give you a warning saying you are using an illegal offset. PHP therefore automatically assumes you are looking for the first element in the array or letter in this case.

Comment: If I copy and paste this into Netbeans I get an illegal offset error. This is mainly because you can only use integer keys when using `$a` as an array. Are you writing this in a completely blank file?

Comment: yes, it is just an empty php file. Interesting that netbeans does some extra checks.

Comment: I have tried this again in another editor. There seems to be no error in the code. I get the expected result now. This is strange indeed :D

Answer (score 0):

it works as expected for... it returned false... but when I force it to return true ... itz throws an error saying illegal offset somekind.... but still output the first string.... as anystring casted as int equals to 0.. check the version of php you are using bro... I used notepad++ to create the php file... no special ide...